# Sets without Dirichlet/polar density

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $K$ be a number field with norm $N=N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}$, $\mathcal{P}$ its set of prime ideals, and $A\subset\mathcal{P}$. We say that the *Dirichlet density* is $$\delta^D(A):=\lim\limits_{s\to1^+}\frac{\sum\limits_{p\in A}N(p)^{-s}}{-\log(s-1)}$$
and the *polar density* $\delta^P(A)$ is $\frac{m}{n}$, where $A$'s Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_A(s):=\prod\limits_{p\in A}(1-N(p)^{-s})^{-1}$ has its $n$th power with a pole of order $m$. **For each of these notions of density, what is an example of a set of primes on which the densities are not defined?**

I know that such sets must exist via the theorem "if $\delta^P(A)$ exists then $\delta^D(A)$ exists and they are equal" so by implication the hypothesis must not always hold. For an instance where $\delta^P$ does not exist, it would be especially intriguing if $\delta^D$ *did* exist.

---

One example along these lines is for *natural density*,
$$\delta^N(A):=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\#\{p\in A:N(p)<x\}}{\#\{p\in\mathcal{P}:N(p)<x\}}:$$
enumerate $\mathcal{P}$ by increasing norm and going down the list, include enough primes to bring the quotient to above $\frac{3}{4}$, then ignore enough primes to being it below $\frac{1}{4}$, then continue alternating indefinitely, so that the limit does not actually exist. Could something like this work for $\delta^D$?

Answer (score 1):

It works the same way for $A$ a set of integer primes, and yes the same idea works for the weaker density $\lim\limits_{s\to1^+}\frac{\sum\limits_{p\in A}N(p)^{-s}}{-\log(s-1)}$.

This is because $\frac{\sum\limits_{p\in A}N(p)^{-s}}{-\log(s-1)}$ can be $\epsilon$ approximated by just knowing the elements of $A$ whose norm is $\in [l_{s,\epsilon} , L_{s,\epsilon}]$ with $$\lim_{s\to 1}l_{s,\epsilon} =\infty,\quad \lim_{s\to 1} L_{s,\epsilon}=\infty$$

Fix $\epsilon=10^{-2}$, choose $s_k\to 1$ such that $l_{s_k,\epsilon} >L_{s_{k-1},\epsilon}$, you will be able to construct $A$ such that
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{p\in A}N(p)^{-s_k}}{-\log(s_k-1)}\in \frac{1}2+\frac{(-1)^k}4+[-\epsilon,\epsilon] $$

Comment: Great, makes sense that this idea would work for both natural and Dirichlet densities since they both entail essentially counting the primes one by one. Do you know if this idea also carries over to polar densities, where the role of counting is a lot less clear?

Comment: We already said that $\frac{\sum\limits_{p\in A}N(p)^{-s_k}}{-\log(s_k-1)}$ can oscillate, the "polar density" seems to be just a weird way to say that we are interested in this limit if it exists (I don't see the point of requiring that the $n$-th power of $\prod\limits_{p\in A}(1-N(p)^{-s})^{-1}$ has a pole)